# Binding a constructor argument based on the Annotation of the class

Tags: guice, guice-3

I have an interface: **InterfaceA**.

I have a class: **ConcreteA**.

I also have two annotations: **@AnnotA** and **@AnnotB**.

I have done the following bindings:

```java
bind(InterfaceA).annotatedWith(AnnotA).to(ConcreteA);
bind(InterfaceA).annotatedWith(AnnotB).to(ConcreteA);
```

Next, class ConcreteA has a constructor that takes a `String` argument called **hostName**.

```java
class ConcreteA
{
    @Inject
    public ConcreteA(@Named("hostName") hostName) {
    }

    ... <rest of class>
}
```

**I need code to describe the following:**

**If ConcretaA is using @AnnotA then bind hostName with String value of 'localhost'**

**If ConcreteA is using @AnnotB then bind hostName with String value of 'externalhost'**

**Any ideas of a solution for this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case, you might consider putting each binding in its own private module.

```
class MyModule() { 
  install(new PrivateModule() {
    public void configure() {
       bind(InterfaceA).to(ConcreteA);
       bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("hostName").to("localhost");
       expose(InterfaceA).annotatedWith(AnnotA.class);
    }});
  install(new PrivateModule() {
    public void configure() {
       bind(InterfaceA).to(ConcreteB);
       bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("hostName").to("externalhost");
       expose(InterfaceA).annotatedWith(AnnotB.class);
    }});
}
```

(This is from memory and syntax may not be 100% correct.)

For more detail, start with [the Guice FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions), and search that page for "robot legs" -- I'm not joking :)

There is even more detail behind the two additional links from that section of the FAQ.

Comment: I'm currently reading the Robot Legs problem, but note that there is no ConcreteB class. There is only one ConcreteA class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example code listing for solving the robot two legs problem:

http://pastie.org/368348