# Simple usage of private modules and/or providers

Tags: java, guice

New to Guice, so I'm looking into its expressive power.  Suppose I have classes as follows:

```
public class Data {
    @Inject
    public Data(@Named("First") String first, @Named("Second") String second) { ... }
}

public class DataUser1 {
    @Inject
    public DataUser1(Data data) { ... }
}

public class DataUser2 {
    @Inject
    public DataUser2(Data data) { ... }
}
```

How do I create a module such that when I call `injector.getInstance(DataUser1.class)` I get something equivalent to `new DataUser1(new Data("foo", "bar"))` while having `injector.getInstance(DataUser2.class)` I get something equivalent to `new DataUser2(new Data("foo2", "bar2"))`?

Also related, how do I create a module for which I may need to get two instances of `DataUser1`, each of which using different `Data` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [private modules](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) for creating graphs of objects which are almost the same but differ in particular details.

```
public class DataUser1Module extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("First")).to("foo");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("Second")).to("bar");

        bind(Data.class);
        bind(DataUser1.class);

        expose(DataUser1.class);
    }
}

public class DataUser2Module extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("First")).to("foo2");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("Second")).to("bar2");

        bind(Data.class);
        bind(DataUser2.class);

        expose(DataUser2.class);
    }
}

Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new DataUser1Module(), new DataUser2Module());
DataUser1 dataUser1 = injector.getInstance(DataUser1.class);
DataUser2 dataUser2 = injector.getInstance(DataUser2.class);
```

You do the same thing if you need two instances of `DataUser1` with different `Data`s, but you use annotations to differentiate between them:

```
public class DataUser1Module1 extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("First")).to("foo");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("Second")).to("bar");

        bind(Data.class);
        bind(DataUser1.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("1")).to(DataUser1.class);

        expose(DataUser1.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("1"));
    }
}

public class DataUser1Module2 extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("First")).to("foo2");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("Second")).to("bar2");

        bind(Data.class);
        bind(DataUser1.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("2")).to(DataUser1.class);

        expose(DataUser1.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("2"));
    }
}

Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new DataUser1Module1(), new DataUser1Module2());
DataUser1 dataUser11 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(DataUser1.class, Names.named("1"));
DataUser1 dataUser12 = injector.getInstance(Key.get(DataUser1.class, Names.named("2"));
```

This pattern is [described](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_build_two_similar_but_slightly_different_trees_of_objec) in Guice FAQ.

See also these questions:

- [Binding a constructor argument based on the Annotation of the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660374/binding-a-constructor-argument-based-on-the-annotation-of-the-class/7670044)
- [How do I bind Different Interfaces using Google Guice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795585/how-do-i-bind-different-interfaces-using-google-guice/2799542)